# Can't see SQL views over VPN but can see tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, vpn

For over a year, I and all of my users were able to access SQL views across our VPN. As of a few months ago, neither I nor any of my other users can access the views. Tables are visible, but views are not. The same users, including myself, have no trouble accessing views while locally connected to the LAN. I've contacted our network admin and he has no clue. Unsure of what may have changed. Suggestions?

EDIT: This is via ODBC connection. When browsing the connection, the views aren't there and an Excel sheet which links to a view via ODBC won't refresh.

Comment: To clarify is it that you can't see them in the object explorer, or you can't select from them? If it's the latter is there an error message when you try?

Comment: Contact your DBA, who needs to set permissions for the views for the VPN user(s).  These permissions are held in SQLServer  at either DB level or Server level.